# Doctrine/MySql relationship with a multi-column PK table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

My Post model in schema.yml (Symfony 1.4) looks like this:

```
Post:
  columns:
    id: { type: bigint, notnull: true, primary: true }
    blog_id: { type: bigint, notnull: true, primary: true }
    user_id: { type: bigint, notnull: true }
    subject: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    short_body: { type: text, notnull: true }
    long_body: { type: text }
```

as you can see Post has a multi-column PK. My question is **"How can I create n:1 relationship with this model?"**

As an example, I want something like this:

```
PostComment:
  columns:
    post_id: { type: bigint, notnull: true }
    blog_id: { type: bigint, notnull: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    email: { type: string(255) }
    text: { type: text, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Post:
      #Here is my problem. What should I write here?
      local: ????
      foreign: ????
      foreignAlias: Comments
      onDelete: cascade
      onUpdate: cascade
```

How can I handle this type of relationship?

Comment: i am not familiar with this notation but you need a one to many .  Also postcomment should have its id i guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.
You can add another primary key to your Post model, and keeping another couple of fields as unique. If you do so, I strongly advice to make "id" your primary key and use another field name as unique along with "blog_id".
Then, just use relations as usual from PostComment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But another question, "How can i create a multi-column unique constraint in yml syntax?"

Comment: See http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer-Doctrine#chapter_08_sub_indexes